# Windows 8.1 XAMPP MySQL Service detected with wrong path

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

I am new to this forum so please bear with me.
I have been trying for a few hours to get MySQL to start in XAMPP for Windows 8.1 which I just installed for the first time. The error code is below.
Based on other posts I have read, here is what I have already tried:
It says I am not running with administrator rights but I went to Control Panel User Accounts and it says that I am an administrator and the only administrator
I went into Program Files(x86) and there is no MySQL folder there.
I tried going into services. MySQL is Stopped. I can't start it; it says Windows can't find the file.
I edited both the ini files for MySQL and php to change the port from 3306 to 3308. 
I tried going into cmd to delete mysql and also to create a service entry. Both times I got an error message that said "Open Service FAILED 5: Access is Denied.
I'd appreciate any help you can give to get this working. Thanks.

```
7:32:33 PM  [main]  Initializing Control Panel
7:32:33 PM  [main]  Windows Version: Windows 8  64-bit
7:32:33 PM  [main]  XAMPP Version: 1.8.3
7:32:33 PM  [main]  Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
7:32:33 PM  [main]  You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
7:32:33 PM  [main]  most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
7:32:33 PM  [main]  there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
7:32:33 PM  [main]  about running this application with administrator rights!
7:32:33 PM  [main]  XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
7:32:33 PM  [main]  Checking for prerequisites
7:32:33 PM  [main]  All prerequisites found
7:32:33 PM  [main]  Initializing Modules
7:32:33 PM  [Apache]    XAMPP Apache is already running on port 80
7:32:33 PM  [Apache]    XAMPP Apache is already running on port 443
7:32:33 PM  [mysql]     MySQL Service detected with wrong path
7:32:33 PM  [mysql]     Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
7:32:33 PM  [mysql]     Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
7:32:33 PM  [mysql]     Found Path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL
7:32:33 PM  [mysql]     Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
7:32:33 PM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
7:32:33 PM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
7:32:41 PM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

Answer (score 3):

**Start -> Run -> `regedit`.**

> It involves editing the registry, but service information can be found
>   in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services. Find the **mysql**
>   service you want to redirect, locate the ImagePath subkey and change
>   that value.

there you can set your default path :)

Comment: Thanks @Chirag Rathod. Really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This issue i faced too, the way to resolve this is you have to remove the old mysql file from `system registery`.

`goto start--> regedit.exe`

open it, on the left site tab of the following window proceed to

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE --> SOFTWARE`

under the software check for the `mysql` folder and delete it, then restart the pc and try to connect the mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Go to start menu and search for "service". In this service menu find MySql and click stop to stop this service. close your service window and Uninstall your XAMPP. After that Uninstall your previous Mysql Server(if installed). Then delete your XAMPP folder (c:\xampp) and delete mysql folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL). Cleanup your registry.
I use Glary Utilities to cleanup registry error. (http://download.glarysoft.com/gu5setup.exe). In advance tab of *Glary Utilities* click repair under windows registry. Select deep scan and repair your registry.
then restart your computer and reinstall ZAMPP. and run your mysql server. i think this way you can solve your problem without hampering your windows.

---

**Note:** Please backup your data and then start this process.

---

Please reply me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Go to start
Type regedit

Navigate to
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services

Search for Mysql
Change ImagePath subkey and change that value.
Change path to mysql

Before
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL

"C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini" MySQL

[image]